# Laravel 5.5 : Not Receiving Password Reset Link

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, cpanel, mailtrap

When I using my Laravel application in **locally** and click "Send password Reset link" button this action is sending a password reset link in **Mailtrap**. But after deploying project on **cPanel**, this action is not sending a password reset link to **selected mail address**. What should I do?

**.env file:**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=**************
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=************

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=*****
DB_USERNAME=*****
DB_PASSWORD=*****

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="mail.dmdhakamanpower.com"

MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST="mail.dmdhakamanpower.com"
MAIL_PORT="465"
MAIL_USERNAME="ddms@dmdhakamanpower.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="SSL"

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTOyD.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using different SMTP server for sending emails after deploy?

I think that the best shot for you right now is to try different server for handling emails and see if it works. If so, then you probably have bad configuration of your own email server.

Comment: how do I know - this is smtp server in Cpanel??

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Can you try for example [Sendinblue's](https://www.sendinblue.com) SMTP or other provider and check, if the issue still occurs?